# Concatenar valores de distintas filas SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g

paso a detallar el problema que tengo, una consulta me devuelve los siguientes resultados

```
ID               email           teléfono
1               x@x.com          111111111
2               a@a.com          222222222
2               p@p.com          222222222
3               j@j.com          333333333
3               j@j.com          444444444
```

Como pueden ver el ID 2 tiene dos correos y 1 teléfono mientras que el id 3 tiene 1 correo y 2 teléfonos, lo que necesito hacer es agruparlos de la siguiente forma

```
ID               email                teléfono
1               x@x.com               111111111
2               a@a.com,p@p.com       222222222
3               j@j.com               333333333,444444444
```

Al principio se me había ocurrido usar LISTAGG, pero tengo la versión ORACLE 11.1.

Comment: Pude lograrlo con la función XMLAGG

Comment: Pon tu respuesta entonces ya que puede ser util a otros miembros de la comunidad